# Is it possible to create github repository for my project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to create github repository for my project in Visual Studio Code, 
and commit all the files?

I have not found a single example where a repository is created from VSCode.

Comment: You need to create a repository on GitHub first. But yes, VSCode can initialise a *git* repository which you can then push to your github repository.

Comment: I know how to initialize, but what I am asking is - how I can create a repository on Github from VScode without first creating it on Github.

Comment: I understood your question, my comment was more along the lines of 'No, you need to create a repository on GitHub first'. There may be extensions to do so, but VSCode does not ship with them by default.

Comment: understand, thank you

Answer (score 20):

Now, there is also a "Publish to Github" button in the "Source Control" part, when there is no git repository, to directly create a repository on github.

[image: Publish to Github button]

If you click on it, by default, VSCode propose (in the main bar) to create a private or a public repository with the project's folder name.

[image: main bar]

Comment: This one should verfy as the right answer ✅

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new file in VS Code. [Local file created in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceopz.png)

Go to Source Control. You will have an option to Initialize Repository, which inturn creates a repo in Github.
Note : You need to connect to your github account before hand.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation on this page on how to initialize a repository in vsCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol

EDIT:

Another link that should be helpful: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/versioncontrol

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no information about github repository creation from the VSCode in the provided links :(

Answer (score 0):

Use GitHub API to create repo. Outside of the API, there's no way to create a repo on GitHub via the command line.

```
curl -u 'username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"projectname","description":"project desc"}'

git remote add origin git@github.com:nyeates/projectname.git
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it's currently not possible with a default installation of VS Code. But you can make it work like this:

1. Add the REST API client by Huachao Mao to VS Code (others may work, haven't tested).
2. [Create a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) in GitHub.
3. Create a new temporary file and enter the following text:
   `curl -u 'myGitHubUsername:myToken' "https://api.github.com/user/repos" -d '{"name":"MyNewRepo","description":"Repo Description"}'`
4. Then select the line, press F1, look for "REST" in the search field and run the command "Rest Client: Send request"
5. After a short while you should be able to add the new remote repo using onboard tools.

Obviously, this is too elaborate for a one-time use. But once it's all set up, it's quite easy to create new repos or interact with the GitHub API in other ways.